# Compare dates issue - javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I need to compare dates in javascript.
After attempt many ways...
I choose:

```
    var endDate = new Date(secondDate.getYear(), secondDate.getMonth(), secondDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0,0);

    var startDate = new Date(firstDate.getYear(), firstDate.getMonth(), firstDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (endDate.getTime() >= startDate.getTime()) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    else {
        isValid = false;
    }
```

In my situation:

---startDate = Tue Apr 01 1997 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time) (i.e, 01/04/1997)

---endDate = Thu Jul 26 114 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time) (i.e, 26/07/2014)

You see? startDate is small then endDate, right?

**But:**

---endDate.getTime() returns:       **-58551904800000**

---startTime.getTime() returns: **859845600000**

**so,** endDate.getTime() >= startDate.getTime()  **returns false...**

In other situation, it works well:

---startDate: Sat Jul 21 114 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time) (i.e, 21/07/2014)

---endDate: Sat Jul 28 114 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time) (i.e, 28/07/2014)

---startDate.getTime() returns **-58552336800000**

---endDate.getTime() returns **-58551732000000**

**so,** endDate.getTime() >= startDate.getTime()  **returns true...**

It seems like that javascript functions have another behavior for dates after year 2000.

What should I do? which code will be match to all of the optional situations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, after I read Josh and ghusse answers and advice:

Use getFullYear(), instead getYear(), and all will work O.K.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have a problem with your end dates :

```
Thu Jul 26 114 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Does not mean 21/07/2014 but **21/07/114**

According to [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), here are 2 correct ways of creating your date:

```
var endDate = new Date(21, 6, 2014);

// Or a string corresponding to a version of ISO8601
var endDate = new Date('2014-07-21T00:00:00z+3');
```

Comment: LOL. I can't get an idea why first date is ok but second is not. getUTCFullYear   can solve this probably )

Comment: It is javascript behavior! in javascript, new Date('Sat Jul 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)').getYear() - returns 114. why? why doesn't it return 2014???

Comment: answer edited. Not all string formats are supported by the Date constructor in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah like ghusse said, there is a problem with your end time if you fixed it so it was 2014 you would get a result such as 1406329200000 instead of -58551904800000